# How to instantiate this map of structs

Tags: go

Here is my struct and instantiation:

```golang
    type mxSet struct {
        domainLock sync.RWMutex
        connections []chan *decodejson.RcptEntity
    }

    var connMap = make(map[string]*mxSet)
```

1. How do I make a buffered channel when it's inside a struct inside a map? These channels correspond to TCP connections I have open, so I need to be able to dynamically open/close them.
2. How do I also instantiate the `sync.RWMutex` at the same time?

More context: What I am trying to do is maintain a map of TCP connections open to a domain. The []chan is how I send data into a specific TCP connections for a specific domain.

Please offer a conceptual explanation of what needs to happen here as well as code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If no value is in the map, then create the value and add to the map.

```
 mx, ok := connMap[key]
 if !ok {
     mx = &mxSet{}
     connMap[key] = mx
 }
 ... use mx as needed needed.
```

The zero values of the sync.RwMutex and the slice of channels are ready to use. No code is required to set them up.